# How to maintain only four lines in my file in shell scripting?

Tags: shell-script, files, logs

Input file:

```
01.05.2016 87893938
02.05.2016 35435345  
03.05.2016 35435345  
04.05.2016 12345678
```

I want to keep only four lines in my file. that means if date 05.05.2016 6905698 is inserted then first line of my file will be removed. I only want to keep last four days data in my file.

Output file:

```
02.05.2016 35435345  
03.05.2016 35435345  
04.05.2016 12345678  
05.05.2016 89459678
```

Comment: What process will add lines to the end of your file? (How will you know that the file has been updated, or - how often do you want to check?)

Comment: have you tried `tail -4 ` ?

Comment: just a note that '6905698' does not show up in your sample output file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cp -p file file.orig && \
tail -n 4 file.orig > file && \
rm file.orig
```

This will [copy the original file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/117549) to a backup copy, retrieve only the last 4 lines from the backup copy, put those 4 lines into the original file name, then remove the backup copy.

Comment: `tail -n4 file > file.orig && cat file.orig > file && rm -f file.orig` will be more efficient for large files. It also fails "safely" if someone tried `mkdir file.orig` first.

Comment: true! it could also be improved with `mktemp`

Comment: cat your_filename | tail -n 4 > newfilename,,,,writes the last 4 lines to your new file, put this in a script and your can call the script as per your convenience !